# functions and class in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web-deployment

like in class component we give state inside a constructor

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {....}
```

like this, but I am wondering how this can be done in the function?

Answer (score 0):

If you mean hook functions you can use it as follow:

```
const [state, setState] = useState({...});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import React, {useState} from 'react'

const Component = () => {
    const [state, setState] = useState({});

    return <span>{JSON.stringlify(state)}</span>
}
```